# Unresolved References in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Let's say I have a project, where (somewhere) the following function is documented:

```
.. exmpl:cfunction:: ExMpl* ExMplSet( int flags, int size, ExStorage* storage )
```

Somewhere else in that project's documentation we have a reference, that looks like this:

```
:exmpl:cfunc:`ExMplSet`
```

Everything seems legit and there are other examples of this use in documentation, but as the output Sphinx gives a warning:

```
~/some_folder/some_file:320: WARNING: unresolved reference: u'ExMplSet' - u'cfunc'
```

There is no link as there should be and 100+ warnings (for the whole project) aren't really that good.

These exact examples are of course made-up. What I'm asking for is some kind of a hint, where to look for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect it to be split over separate lines. Target on one, definition on the other:

```
.. exmpl:cfunction:: ExMplSet

ExMpl* ExMplSet( int flags, int size, ExStorage* storage )
```

Another option (I cannot check this right now) is that you're missing a colon in front of "exmpl:"